# telegram bot отвечает на сообщение со второго раза

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот, telebot

Как побороть проблему, что бот реагирует на сообщение со второго раза?
Вот участок кода, в котором проблема:

```
def display_recs(message):
    mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM opros_100;')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(mycursor.fetchall())
    df1.columns = [x[0] for x in mycursor.description]
    print(df1)
    data1 = Dataset.load_from_df(df1[['userId', 'movieId', 'rating']], reader2)
    trainset__ = data1.build_full_trainset()
    testset__ = trainset__.build_anti_testset()
    pred_list = algo.test(testset__)
    top_n = get_top_n_movies(message.from_user.id, pred_list, 5, df_100)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Рекомендация для тебя")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                        f'{top_n["title"][:5]}')
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери действие', reply_markup=main_kb)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, main_buttons)


def display_rated(message):
    mycursor.execute('SELECT title, rating FROM opros_100 WHERE userId=%s', (message.from_user.id,))
    result = mycursor.fetchall()
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(result)):
        temp.append(f'{result[i][0]} -- {result[i][1]}')
    rated = '\n'.join(temp)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Оцененные фильмы:\n{rated}')
    message = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери действие', reply_markup=main_kb)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, main_buttons)

def main_buttons(message):
    if message.text == 'Получить рекомендации':
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, display_recs)
    if message.text == 'Посмотреть оцененные фильмы':
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, display_rated)
```

Подозреваю, что проблема в функции main_buttons, так как при отправке первого сообщения, вроде бы, идет заход в условие с проверкой текста сообщения, а с отправкой второго сообщения идет переход на нужную функцию.

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также есть такой момент, что при отправке первым сообщением команды на вывод рекомендаций, а вторым просмотр оценённых фильмов, то срабатывает все равно первая команда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видимо проблема с `register_next_step_handler()`, но не могу придумать, как исправить, чтобы все было корректно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит из-за неразберихи в части :

```
if message.text == 'Получить рекомендации':
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, display_recs)
if message.text == 'Посмотреть оцененные фильмы':
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, display_rated)
```

Попробую объяснить понятнее. Сам метод `register_next_step_handler()`  ждет сообщения пользователя, чтобы после этого перейти к следующей части. А у Вас сначала функция `If` проверяет сообщение и запускает `bot.register_next_step_handler`, после чего этот метод ожидает еще одного сообщения, чтобы перейти ко второй части (def)

Решение проблемы я вижу в переходе сразу к функции `def display_rated / recs`, отставив `register_next_step_handler`

**Если возникли вопросы, задавайте их смело в комментариях.**

Comment: Но нужно же в зависимости от сообщения пользователя переходить к display_recs/rated, как тогда делать проверку?

Comment: Вы, видно, меня не поняли. Метод register_next_step_handler просто ждет сообщения пользователя, когда оно уже получено. Я предлагаю вместо этого метода вызывать к функции display_recs/rated, в зависимости от сообщения. Проверка же будет проводиться в самой конструкции "if"

Comment: действительно, спасибо большое!